# Where to put a main.scss file in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to ask on where should I put for example a main.scss file where it can be used by all of the components. I try to put a css in app.components.ts (root component) but it doesn't apply the styles in one of my component.

Solved!

I add the main.scss in the styles in angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
        "assets/scss/main.scss"
      ],
```

After than no need for import in the index.html

Comment: I have got that in root directry `/src`

Answer (score 0):

In index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/main.scss">
```

/assets/styles -> should be your assets folder where you will have images, fonts, css etc.

Comment: it should be in css right when I link it because it is not working when It is in .scss. My problem now is how will i convert it to .css automatically when there's a changes in the main.scss

Comment: can you mention your folder structure in the question.